# Add a secret to Vault through ARM without knowing it

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

I am working with Visual Studio 2019 to create ARM template.

To deploy Resource on Azure, Visual Studio use a powershell, a json parameter and another json for resource.

I have created a keyvault with ARM template in azure.
I have put a secret in it.
Everything is created as expected.

Now, I don't like to put the password in clear text inside the json.

I'm looking for a way to put a secret without knowing the value by myself.
I want to keep thing simple.

Do you know a way to make ARM generate a password for me ? (I don't need to know the password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use either [utcNow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#utcnow) function or [deployment().name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-deployment#deployment) function as a pseudo random generator combined with [uniqueString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#uniquestring) function. You could also use resourceGroup().id to ensure unique secrets are generated for each resource group.

That's the best you can get inside arm templates.

Another option would be to call an Azure Function that would generate the password for you and you would use that in the ARM Template.

Comment: Thanks you 4c74356b41, I see that you use this kind of tips to generate your username :D

Comment: this is golden ;)